# Processing center the zoom of a movie

Tags: processing, zooming, movie

I created an application that is divided into 2 movies. One movie is split into four quadrants, while the other is meant to provide a view a quadrant that your mouse is over. I have added a function that allows you to zoom in or out of the movie when clicking the plus or minus button, however the zoom does not center for each quadrant. The center is off a bit for each quadrant and makes the view of the larger movie look looks split.

```
<!--   
    //using processing video and movie
    import processing.video.*;
    Movie movie;

    //size of buttons and the integers that load a view to the big square
    int bigX=0;
    int bigY=0;
    int toolSize = 20;

    //positions for each buttom
    int plusX, plusY;
    int minusX, minusY;
    int speed = 1;
    float zoomCounter;
    int scaleW;
    int scaleH;
    int progress;
    String current = "";
    boolean play;
    float scaler = 1;

    //naming our buttons
    PImage plus;
    PImage minus;
    String view;

    //These integers are for testing zoom
    int scale = 1;
    int maxScale = 5;
    float zoomFactor = 0.4;
    int imgW;
    int imgH;

    void setup() {
    size(1280, 360);
    background(0);
    // Load and play the video in a loop
    movie = new Movie(this, "video.mov");
    movie.play();

      movie.speed(speed);

      //set our button images
      plus = loadImage("Plus.png");
      minus = loadImage("Minus.png");

     //setting the position of our buttons 
       plusX = width/4 + 60;
       plusY = height/2 + 130;
       minusX = width/4 + 90;
       minusY = height/2 + 130;
       scale = 1;
       scaleW = width;
       scaleH = height*2;
    }

    void movieEvent(Movie m) {
      m.read();
}

    void draw() {
    //translate(width/2,height/2);
    //big movie
    image(movie, bigX, bigY, scaleW, scaleH);
    //small movie
    image(movie, width/2, 0, width/2, height);

    fill(255, 100);
    //Box One - Top Left
    if (mouseX>width/2 && mouseX<width*.75 && mouseY<height/2) {
    rect(width/2, 0, 320, 180);
    bigX=0;
    bigY=0;
    }
    //Box Two - Top Right
    if (mouseX>width*.75 && mouseY<height/2) {
    rect(width*.75, 0, 320, 180);
    bigX=-640;
    bigY=0;
    }
    //Box Three - Bottom Left
    if (mouseX>width/2 && mouseX<width*.75 && mouseY>height/2) {
    rect(width/2, height/2, 320, 180);
    bigX=0;
    bigY=-360;
    }
    //Box Four - Bottom Right
    if (mouseX>width*.75  && mouseY>height/2) {
    rect(width*.75, height/2, 320, 180);
    bigX=-640;
    bigY=-360;
    }
    //Draws buttons
    image(plus, plusX, plusY, toolSize, toolSize);
    image(minus, minusX, minusY, toolSize, toolSize);
    }

    class Buttons{
    int buttonX;
    int buttonY;
    int buttonWidth;
    int buttonHeight;
    int mouseposX;
    int mouseposY;
    boolean overButton;
    boolean buttonOn;
    PImage img;
    String currentButton;
    boolean pressed;


    Buttons(int tempbuttonX, int tempbuttonY, int toolsize, int 
    tempmouseposX, 
    int tempmouseposY, boolean overButton, boolean tempbuttonOn, PImage img, 
    String currentButton, boolean pressed)
    {
    buttonX = tempbuttonX;
    buttonY = tempbuttonY;
    buttonWidth = toolsize;
    buttonHeight = toolsize;
    mouseposX = tempmouseposX;
    mouseposY = tempmouseposY;
    overButton = false;
    pressed = false;
    buttonOn = tempbuttonOn;
    currentButton = "";
    pressed = false;
    }
    }
    boolean overButton(int x, int y, int width, int height)  {
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
    mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }


    void mousePressed()
    {
      redraw(toolSize);
      if (current == "Plus")
        {
          if(zoomCounter <= 10)
          {
            zoomCounter += 1;
            scaleH += 30;
            scaleW += 30;
          }
                  }
         else if (current == "Minus")
        {
         if(zoomCounter >= 1)
         {
              scaleH -=30;
           scaleW -=30;
          }
        }
      }
    void redraw(int toolSize) {
    if ((overButton(plusX, plusY, toolSize, toolSize)))
    {
        current = "Plus";
         plus.filter(GRAY);
         minus.filter(GRAY);
    }
    else if ((overButton(minusX, minusY, toolSize, toolSize)))
    {      current = "Minus";
         plus.filter(GRAY);
         minus.filter(GRAY);
    }
    } zoomCounter -= 1; -->
```

In order to center each view, I tried surrounding the integer zoomCounter using translate () and my movies but it zoomed into the entire view and I had to note it out under draw. I am currently using an else if statement to manipulate the amount of zoom.